# Select certain ID's from MYSQL and save as PHP Vars

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-in

I want to select certain id's from mysql and save the results into associated php vars:

For Example:
save **COL "Name"** from **ID "20"** to Var: **$id20 = "Name";**

```
$queryCS = 'SELECT * FROM ya_events WHERE id IN (20, 16, 21, 37, 40)';

$result = mysql_query($queryCS,$yaDB);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == '') {'';} else 
{while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$id.$row['id'] = $row['name'];

}};

echo "ID16: ".$id16;
```

But $id16 seems to be empty

Comment: post insert code  here

Comment: what is it  save ROW "Name" from ID "20" to Var: $id20 = "Name"?

Comment: `${'id' . $row['id']} = $row['name']` ... though, using arrays seems more useful.

Comment: This is what i want to do, I want to save the "name" Col from id20 to PHP-Variable $id20 = "Content of Name Col in id21";

Comment: THANKS JACK, this is working fine!

Comment: You should use an array instead see Jack's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a better idea to use arrays:

```
while (...) {
    $ids[$row['id']] = $row['name'];
}

echo $ids[16];
```

But, if you really want a bunch of variables lying around:

```
${'id' . $row['id']} = $row['name'];
```

Comment: In addition, `foreach ($ids as $id => $name) { echo $id, " => ", $name, "\n"; }` Would also be an easy way to read each pair or id and name in case you save it on an array like Jack suggested.

Comment: Jack your first solution is working for me: ${'id' . $row['id']} = $row['name']; THX

Comment: @user2987790 Very well, I've added that to my answer; but you should really consider arrays for containment.

Comment: ok, i'll try the array. Is an array better because of perfomance reasons?

Comment: It's not so much performance reasons ... it's grouping same kind of variables together.

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $this_variable_name = 'id' . $row['id'];  // $this_variable_name = 'id16';


    // Use PHP variable variables to define
    // and set values for variables like $id16

    $$this_variable_name = $row['name'];
};

echo "ID16: ".$id16;
```